# Why is it write: "No overload for 'Click_Edit' matches delegate 'EventHandler'"

Tags: c#, html, sql, sharp

I'm trying to build a site in html. I already build registery, login, home and did a table of all the people who have been subscribe to my site. now, I want an option that I can delete and update my table of users. now, it writes me "No overload for 'Click_Edit' matches delegate 'EventHandler'", about the buttens. This or that way, the buttens are not working.

deleteapdate.aspx

```
<form id="deleteForm" method="post" runat="server">
<div style="margin-left:15px; margin-top:20px;">

    <button runat="server" onserverclick="Click_Delete">Delete</button>&nbsp
    <button  runat="server" onserverclick="Click_Edit">Update</button>&nbsp
    <%--<button style="width: 90px; height: 40px;" runat="server" onserverclick="Click_Delete" value="delete">Delete</button>&nbsp
    <button style="width: 90px; height: 40px;"  runat="server" onserverclick="Edit" value="update">Update</button>--%>


    <%--<input type="button" value="Delete" name="btnDelete" id="btnDelete" runat="server"  />
    <input type="button" value="Update" name="btnUpdate" id="btnUpdate" runat="server"  />--%>

    </div> <br />








    <div id="tableDiv" runat="server" style="border: 1px;">

    </div>
    <P runat="server" id="mess"></P>
    </form>
```

delete.aspx.cs

```
 public partial class DeleteUpdate : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    //public string BuildUsersTable(DataTable dt)
    //{
    //    string str = "<table class= 'usersTable' align='center'>";
    //}
    public string st = "";
    public string msg = "";
    public string sqlDelete = "";

    public void Click_Delete(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int userId;
        List<int> usersList = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 1; i < Request.Form.Count; i++)
        {
            if (Request.Form.AllKeys[i].Contains("chk"))
            {
                userId = int.Parse(Request.Form.AllKeys[i].Remove(0, 3));
                usersList.Add(userId);
            }
        }
        int[] userIdToDelete = usersList.ToArray();
        Helper.Delete(userIdToDelete);

        string SQLStr = "SELECT * FROM " + Helper.tblname;
        DataSet ds = Helper.RetrieveUsersTable(SQLStr);
        string table = Helper.BuildUsersTable(ds.Tables[0]);
        tableDiv.InnerHtml = table;
    }

    public void Click_Edit(ObjectStateFormatter sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < Request.Form.Count; i++)
        {
            if (Request.Form.AllKeys[i].Contains("chk"))
            {
                Session["userToUpdate"] = int.Parse(Request.Form.AllKeys[i].Remove(0, 3));
                Response.Redirect("/pages/UpdateAdmin.aspx");
            }
        }
        mess.InnerHtml = "No user was selscted to edit!";
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["Login"] != null)
        {
            if (!(bool)Session["Admin"])
            {
                Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
            }
            else
            {

                if (!IsPostBack)
                {

                    string SQLStr = "SELECT * FROM " + Helper.tblname;
                    DataSet ds = Helper.RetrieveUsersTable(SQLStr);
                    DataTable dt = ds.Tables[Helper.tblname];
                    string table = Helper.BuildUsersTable(dt);
                    tableDiv.InnerHtml = table;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you use Sharp or did you add the tag because you use C#? The code you show is C#, not C. Please select proper tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `public void Click_Edit(object sender, EventArgs e)` for the function definition. Your method must receive the sender parameter as object type to match the EventHandler delegate definition.

(You will notice that all your other event handlers also use this same format.)